# Return Collection names based on column value in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have 5 collections C1, C2, C3, C4 and N5 each having a last_updated value.

```
db.getCollectionNames().filter(function(c){ return c.indexOf('C')==0})
```

will return me all the collections that start with "C".

Is it possible to go one step ahead and do a filter based on "last_updated" column so that i will get all "C" collections that are updated yesterday.

something like this

```
 db.getCollectionNames().filter(function(c){ return (db.c.find({update_on: "01-Dec-2014"}).count()
 > 1)});
```

Eventhough the query runs fine its not yeilding any result.

Comment: Did you try Changing the check `>1` to `>0` ? And what type of data is present in the `update_on` column? Is it `String` or `ISODate()`?

Comment: Its a String "01-Dec-2014" and > 0 is not giving any results. Even _id query also return empty.                                       > db.getCollectionNames().filter(function(c){ return (db.c.find({_id:"548b1ff498bfb71f682e1aa2"}).co
unt() > 0)});
[ ]

Comment: Please see my answer, you need to use it as `db[c]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `true` even if one record is present is present in the collection for the queried date.

Second, `db.c` is resolved to value `c`,Therefore finding the count of a collection named `c`, which does not exist. To resolve `c` as a variable, we need to use it as `db[c]`.

The modified code below would do that:

```
db.getCollectionNames().filter(function(c){
 var rec = db[c].count({update_on: "01-Dec-2014"});
 return (rec > 0);
})
```