# Determine which Mongo collection an document exists in?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

Is there a way in Meteor/MongoDB to do a find to get the collection an document's `_id` exists in?

What I am trying to accomplish is to create a generic Comments framework for my app, where comments can be applied to several different document types that are saved in multiple Mongo collections.  For instance, comments can be applied to `Pages` as well as `Comments`.  What I need to do is save the comment, then modify the parent document.  I can pass in the `_id` of the parent, but without strong typing I can't figure out if this is a Page or a Comment (or any other "commentable" type I might come up with.

One solution, I think, would be to store the "parent"'s ID in the comment, but I wanted to try to save an array of comments in the parent instead.

Comment: No. You cannot search to find a matching collection for a document. You can only search a collection to find matching documents. I'm not 100% sure what the underlying problem is - could you describe the workings of your proposed comment framework in more detail? Why don't you know the identity of what is being commented on when the comment is created, so you can update the correct parent document? Why can't you just pass the type/collection of the parent document with the _id?

Comment: PLease check this may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725626/return-collection-names-based-on-column-value-in-mongo/27725834#27725834

Comment: @wdberkeley The problem isn't that I don't know what is being commented on.  The problem is I wanted to store the array of comments in the parent, and as such I would need to know which collection it came from so I can do the update.  I think the solution is to turn things on their head and store the "parent_id" in the comment, not the comment _ids in the parent.  I think this gives me a better one-to-many relation anyways, as a comment can only exist in 1 parent.

Comment: Yes, referencing the parent from children is probably a good strategy here. But I still don't understand how you don't know what collection the parent comes from if you know what the parent is at the time of commenting.

Comment: The code I am in is the Meteor.methods code, where I have passed only the params object with the comment and the parent's id.  I was trying to keep this a "generic" method, as I can have comments applied to many different things (pages, blog posts, other comments, products, etc).  Again, the initial idea was to write the comments id into the parent, and in order to do that I would have to know which parent in which collection I had to update.  I would not know that in a server-side method that only has the id of the parent, or even the whole parent object, in question.